# Append The String object on check box selection for iphone

Tags: ios, nsstring, uibutton

I have created a check box on check box selection append the string but when i select
      only one object after that my object contain a comma, i don't want the comma if user
      select only on check box.And if user select all three then comma separated value is fine but when user select the randomly then we have a problem.  Below is my code

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (sender.tag == 0) {
    if (isPaint) {
        isPaint = NO;
        [self.filterDict setValue:@"" forKey:@"one"];
    } else {
        isPaint = YES;
        [self.filterDict setValue:@"1" forKey:@"one"];
    }
}
if (sender.tag == 1) {
    if (isDecor) {
        isDecor = NO;
        [self.filterDict setValue:@"" forKey:@"two"];
    } else {
        isDecor = YES;
        [self.filterDict setValue:@"2" forKey:@"two"];
    }
}
if (sender.tag == 2) {
    if (isCommunity) {
        isCommunity = NO;
        [self.filterDict setValue:@"" forKey:@"three"];
    } else {
        isCommunity = YES;
        [self.filterDict setValue:@"3" forKey:@"three"];
    }
  }

}

- (IBAction)doneFilter:(UIButton *)sender   {
NSMutableString *filterType = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if ([self.filterDict objectForKey:@"one"] != nil) {
        paintStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", [self.filterDict objectForKey:@"one"]];
    } if ([self.filterDict objectForKey:@"two"] != nil) {
        decorStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", [self.filterDict objectForKey:@"two"]];
    } if ([self.filterDict objectForKey:@"three"] != nil) {
        communityStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.filterDict objectForKey:@"three"]];
    }

    if (paintStr != nil) {
        [filterType appendString:paintStr];
    } if (decorStr != nil) {
        [filterType appendString:decorStr];
    } if (communityStr != nil) {
        [filterType appendString:communityStr];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can add "," to all three cases, then *delete* 1 character when you finish composing the final string. make sense?

Comment: BTW - don't use `setValue:forKey:`. Use `setObject:forKey:`.

Comment: I don't have previous selected value. User will select any of three check box. on check box selection i want the result some thing like this. Eg if one check box select then result should be 1 and if user select 2 check box then result should be 1,2. but in my case 1,2,. I don't want a last comma. User can select any of three selection. Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Only append a comma if there is an existing value:

```
- (IBAction)doneFilter:(UIButton *)sender   {
    NSMutableString *filterType = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    paintStr = self.filterDict[@"one"];
    decorStr = self.filterDict[@"two"];
    communityStr = self.filterDict[@"three"];

    if (paintStr) {
        if (filterType.length) {
            [filterType appendString:@","];
        }
        [filterType appendString:paintStr];
    }
    if (decorStr) {
        if (filterType.length) {
            [filterType appendString:@","];
        }
        [filterType appendString:decorStr];
    }
    if (communityStr) {
        if (filterType.length) {
            [filterType appendString:@","];
        }
        [filterType appendString:communityStr];
    }
}
```

Note how this code was cleaned up and updated with modern Objective-C syntax.